# Prevent typing in SearchView before SpannableString

Tags: android, searchview, spannablestring, spannable

Inside android SearchView i made a TextView and added "This Site" to it then converted the view to bitmap and added span using a shape drawable.

I dont want my cursor to type before the Span and `setSelection` doesn't seems to work for me

```
    final SearchView sv = new SearchView(getActivity());

    final String tokenName = "This Site";
    final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    TextView tv = createSearchTokenTextView(tokenName);

    BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) convertViewToDrawable(tv);
    bd.setBounds(0, 0, bd.getIntrinsicWidth(), bd.getIntrinsicHeight());

    sb.append(tokenName + " ");
    sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd), sb.length() - (tokenName.length() + 1), sb.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    Selection.setSelection(sb, 0, sb.toString().length());

    sv.setQuery(sb, false);
```